# Trouble getting href from BeautifulSoup resultSet object, but can get "style" and "class"?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
next_page = ‘https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/tags/series?et=&pageID=1&t='
opened_url = urllib2.urlopen(next_page).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(opened_url)

hrefs = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"col-xs-12 col-sm-10"})
```

`hrefs` now looks like this:

`[<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">\n<a class="series-title" href="/fred2/series/GDPC1" style="font-size:1.2em">Real Gross Domestic Product</a>\n</div>, <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">\n<a class="series-title" href="/fred2/series/CPIAUCSL" style="font-size:1.2em">Consumer Price Index for All Urban Consumers: All Items</a>\n</div>,` ...

I try getting the `href` out of there with something like `hrefs[1]['href']`, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

I just want to get all 18 links off of this page. I suppose I could just convert each element in `hrefs` to string and then just `find` the href in there, but that kind of defeats the purpose of bs4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fetch `a` tag's `href`

```
hrefs = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"col-xs-12 col-sm-10"})
print hrefs[1].find('a')['href']
```

To fetch all the a tag's `href` inside div tags, you could use

```
for tag in hrefs:
    print tag.find('a', href=True)['href']
```